# Please Tell me why does this code generates output 'Base Class'. Although Object is of Derived2 type and reference variable is also of same type

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, output

```
namespace IndiabixConsoleApplication
{ 
    class Baseclass
    { 
        public void fun()
        { 
            Console.Write("Base class" + " ");
        } 
    } 
    class Derived1: Baseclass
    { 
        new void fun()
        {
            Console.Write("Derived1 class" + " "); 
        } 
    } 
    class Derived2: Derived1
    { 
        new void fun()
        { 
            Console.Write("Derived2 class" + " ");
        }
    }
    class Program
    { 
        public static void Main(string[ ] args)
        { 
            Derived2 d = new Derived2(); 
            d.fun(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your derived methods are not `public`, so the only choice the external class (`Program`) has is the public `BaseClass.fun()` method.  If you make `Derived2.fun()` public it will give you the output you are expecting.

Class methods (and properties/fields) are `private` by default unless explicitly set to `public` (or `protected` or `internal`).

Answer (score 0):

You should look up access modifiers. You have declared the fun method as new on the derived classes, but fun on the base class is the only public method. The others are private.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx